# Find the integral: $\int \frac{( x-6)^2}{x^4}\mathrm{d} x$

Tags: calculus

Find the integral: $\int \frac{(x-6)^2}{x^4}\mathrm{d} x$

I have so far  $\int (u)^2(u-6x)^{-4}\mathrm{d} x$

$u= x-6$ and $du=dx$ and $u-6=x$
Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 5):

You don't need substitution. Simply expand $(x-6)^2$ and get $x^2 -12x +36$, and separate these term, i.e. $\frac{x^2 -12x +36}{x^4} = \frac{1}{x^2} - \frac{12}{x^3} + \frac{36}{x^4}$. This form will be familiar to you, integrate directly.

Comment: Makes Sense, however, I imagine it's not reasonable strategy if the power is greater than 2?

Comment: It's still a reasonable strategy as there is no other strategy

Comment: Once the denominator is $x^n$, this strategy provides solution.

Comment: @MonkeyKing apologies for downvoting you, but my cat accidentally stepped on the downvote button (on my iPad). So to make amends I better upvote you.